# Slide show has a strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, slideshow

My slide show (Javascript) works properly since the last slide, but when it be restarted, doesn't stop the assigned freeze time. It is my js code:

```
var pos;
var slides;
var timeOut;
var slideTime = 3000;

window.onload = function (){
    pos = -1;
    var slideContent = document.getElementById("slides");
    slides = slideContent.getElementsByTagName("article");
    initSlides();
};

function initSlides(){
    if (pos !== -1){
        pos++;
        if (pos === slides.length){
            pos = 0;
            exitSlide(slides[slides.length-1], slides[pos]);
        }else{
            exitSlide(slides[pos-1], slides[pos]);
        }
    }else{
        pos ++;
        slides[pos].style.display = "block";
        timeOut = setTimeout(initSlides, slideTime);
    }
}

function changeSlide(next){
    if (next){
        pos++;
        if (pos === slides.length){
            pos = 0;
            exitSlide(slides[slides.length-1], slides[pos]);
        }else{
            exitSlide(slides[pos-1], slides[pos]);
        }
    }else{
        pos --;
        if (pos === -1){
            pos = slides.length - 1;
        }
    }
}

function enterSlide(obj){
    obj.style.display = "block";
    var left = obj.offsetLeft;
    var current = obj.offsetWidth;
    obj.style.marginLeft = current + "px";
    function frame(){
        current -= obj.offsetWidth/120;
        if (current >= left){
            obj.style.marginLeft = current + "px";
        }else{
            clearInterval(id);
            timeOut = setTimeout(initSlides, slideTime);
        }
    }

    var id = setInterval(frame, 1);
}

function exitSlide(obj, objNext){
    clearTimeout(timeOut);
    var left = obj.offsetLeft;
    var current = -obj.offsetWidth;
    function frame(){
        left += current/120;
        if (left >= current){
            obj.style.marginLeft = left + "px";
        }else{
            clearInterval(id);
            obj.style.display = "none";
            enterSlide(objNext);
        }
    }

    var id = setInterval(frame, 1);
}
```

The inspect code console doesn't give me any error, but slide show is so bugged. Since second turn the slides doesn't stop and some time latter, the slides sometimes stops, sometimes be showed but without transaction and sometimes means that works properly but the next slide is bugged too. I don't know why it happends. If you can, help me please.

Comment: Please provide a jsFiddle or codepen. I read your code and for me it could happen because when you restart your slider, you does'nt clear your setInterval in var id.

Comment: What is jsFiddle? And codepen? I'm using clearInterval() at the end of each transaction, is it not enough?

Comment: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) (and same to codepen) are environments that you can simulate your code in them in a way that we can see your code output and regenerate your issue, so we can investigate it...

Answer (score 0):

Finaly, I desisted to my attempt of desing my own slide show and i'm using this plugin: [Slick - the last carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)